# How to call only RESTful endpoint from browser?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

I am trying to create end points programmatically and I don't want to specify end points configuration in config file.

I want to add RESTful end points so after adding RESTful end points I should be able to call those RESTful endpoints from browser.

After adding end points, I have put a debugger on my method but my method is not getting called and I don't see any output.

I am not getting what is wrong with my code. Based on my understanding when I am adding this configuration programmatically then I don't need to define this configuration in config file.

**Wcf Service Code:**

```
public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,          UriTemplate = "Add/{n1}")]
        string Add(string n1);
    }

public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public string Add(string n1)
        {
            return n1;
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>   
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Console App hosting wcf service and adding end points:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), new Uri("http://localhost:56264/CalculatorService.svc"));
            WebHttpBinding webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
            webHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 2;
            webHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647L;
            webHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
            webHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647L;
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), webHttpBinding, "CalculatorService");
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the service host");
            Console.ReadLine();
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Now when I try to call my end point from browser like below, I get nothing in response:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Uri in the [WebServiceHost Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb536017(v=vs.110).aspx) should only include the base address of the service.

Try this code:

```
WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService),
                                                new Uri("http://localhost:56264"));
```

Comment: I tried this but sorry to say i am still unable to call my method